# What "Mechanics can pull codes for many of these sensors" can exactly mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

If any of these sensors are malfunctioning, the "Check Engine" light may come on inside the car, or the engine may run roughly. Mechanics can **pull codes** for many of these sensors to help solve the problem.

A. What is "**pull codes**"?
B. **Mechanics** here is a single noun or working people?

Answer (score 8):

to *pull codes* means to *download* error codes from the computer memory.

*mechanics* refer to those working people that repair mechanical devices.

Answer (score 6):

A.  "pull" = transitive verb, meaning "get information from" (the car's computer)
    "codes" = plural noun, meaning "error codes" (such as numbers, that can be used to look up error descriptions in a table.)

B.  "Mechanics" = plural noun, meaning "people who build and/or fix machines".

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the context here is a car or other motor vehicle.

Modern cars have a lot of sensors throughout the engine and associated systems. These are designed to detect faults with the engine, and to feed information to the engine management computer to allow the engine to adjust itself to operate at peak efficiency in all conditions.

If a fault condition is detected, a fault code is stored in the memory of the engine management computer, and this is generally indicated by the "check engine" light being illuminated.  These codes can be read, or "pulled" by a mechanic, being a person who works on cars. The codes are sometimes very helpful in identifying what is wrong with the car.

Actually, the codes for most cars can be read using a smart phone and a cheap OBD2 Bluetooth adapter, but for information on that sort of thing you'll be better off on the motor vehicle stack exchange.