# "As physics know today" or "As physics knows today"?

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct:

`As physics know today` or `As physics knows today`?

I would be inclined to use the first one, but isn't physics the science name, like a single not plural entity?

I am relating to the word `semantics`. The ending `s` on that word is not technically, a plural, or is a plural that was incorporated to form a singular word. Isn't it?

So, what do you think?

`As physics know today` or `As physics knows today`?

Comment: Have you looked up "physics" in a physical dictionary?  In particular, have you read the definitions of the nouns derived from "physics"?  You might want to replace the word "physics" in your examples with one of those nouns.

Comment: Related question:  [What “Mechanics can pull codes for many of these sensors” can exactly mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82162)

Comment: Neither is a complete sentence on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form

> As physics knows today, ...

Is grammatically correct. "Physics" is the name of a single science or field of study, and so is singular, and takes singular forms.

However, this construction requires personifying "physics" which as a field of study, cannot literally 'know" anything. This is also not a very usual construction.

In my view, it would would be better to say something like

> - The consensus among physicists today is ...
> - Today, physicists generally believe ...
> - The current understanding of physics is ...
> - Current theories of physics state ...
> - Today, physics theories hold that ...
> - The current view in physics is ...

Comment: brilliant explanation. That construction is valid in my natural language but in English that was bothering me as wrong. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

More context and detail about what you're trying to say would be helpful (like some examples of complete sentences). But I suggest:

> As **physicists** (know / have learned / are aware), ...

Possession of knowledge is a trait more commonly attributed to living things than to fields of study.

That said, *physics* is a singular noun, despite the "s." The same is true for *mathematics*, but **not** for *the physical sciences*.

You *can* attribute human traits to non-living things if you know what you're doing. This process is called [anthropomorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropomorphism), but I think that is beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: brilliant explanation. That construction is valid in my natural language but in English that was bothering me as wrong. THANKS!